# How can I maintain a secure automated recognition relationship with remote web servers when comcast keeps changing my IPv6 and IPv4 addresses?

Tags: .htaccess, ipv6, ipv4

It used to be that one's IPv4 would stay the same for months at a time. Now, however, it seems they like to renew your IPs on a near daily basis.

Previous to these shenanigans, during development of a project, I would set the remote system's .htaccess files to accept only my IP and the IPs of my clients.

however, after having a chat with xfinity's ever so unhelpful support staff, I've been notified that there is absolutely zero available method by which I can secure a sustained IP address. Apparently even requesting to have the same IP for an entire day is utterly out of the question.

Google, however uncharacteristically, has yielded nothing but a slew of other customers and developers dealing with a similar issue.

I considered using ngrok, but I don't think they give you an IP address, and if they do it's quite likely shared.

My most recent project is a Shopify app. Shopify apps are nothing but webhooks and www endpoints. With my constantly changing IPs, this has become a near nightmare.

What is everybody else doing these days?

I don't even think there is any way to set an apache .htaccess file to recognize me when my IPs are cycling on a near daily basis.

So - either I'm an idiot and the infamous SE downvote squad will roll through and pummel me into negative points, or this is a valid issue that quite a few others have been wresting with.

Thanks in advance to any help any of you might offer.

Comment: It sounds like you have a home/residential account when you really need a business account. With a business account, you can purchase fixed IP addresses, both IPv4 and IPv6. At some point, your residential ISP will change to CGNAT, and you will then be in for a lot more trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TBH, if you're doing this work as your business and you need a static ip address then you ought to pay for and be using Comcast Business Internet with a static ip address, which is an available option. Unfortunate or unfair as that may seem, that's the cost of doing business. I need a static ip address for my business, so I pay for one.

If that's not something you're willing to do then you could look into a service like No-IP... if you can make your apps and such work with an FQDN rather than an ip address.

Comment: Oh what? You would think that after talking to them for 20 minutes about my situation that they would mention the fact that there was an available business account option with static IPs. *rolls eyes*
Well, thank you for informing me of this. Massively helpful

Comment: Can't believe the above answer was accepted, let alone upvoted. There are many solutions/workarounds. 15! years ago I was already hacking around this problem by using a VPN. There are multiple ways of tackling the problem using a VPN depending on your use case, but it would be easy enough to find a VPN provider that will assign you a static IP address assuming you don't need the additional security of running your own infrastructure. (Just google VPN static IP)

Comment: An alternative would be to use a proxy server.

Comment: Another possibility might be to use an SSH tunnel/SOCKS proxy depending on your level of access to the server.